# parse capital letter month in golang

Tags: date, go, time

I want to parse string like `"25-APR-2019"` to `time.time`

I know parsing date using

```
date, err := time.Parse(layout, stringVariableForDate)
```

But I didn't find layout option in https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants

I can not use JAN, as using this, I am getting error :

```
panic: parsing time "25-APR-2019" as "02-JAN-2006": cannot parse "APR-2019" as "-JAN-"
```

How can I parse date string with month name in capital letter in go-lang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> The recognized month formats are "Jan" and "January".

---

The parse layout abbreviated month format is "Jan". Use "02-Jan-2006" for the parse layout.

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    date, err := time.Parse("02-Jan-2006", "25-APR-2019")
    fmt.Println(date, err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5MRpUrUVJt4

Output:

```
2019-04-25 00:00:00 +0000 UTC <nil>
```